# In Firestore, how can you do a compound query involving a key in a map without creating an index for every key?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore, how can you do a compound query involving a key in a map without creating an index for every key?

For example, consider a collection which holds blog posts, and each blog post has categories.

```
Post {
    title: ..
    ...
    categories: {
        cats: true
        puppies: true
    }   
}
```

In order to query posts in a particular category in a paginated way, we would do something like this:

```
let query = db.collection(`/posts`)
    .where(`categories.${categoryId}`, '==', true)
    .orderBy('createdAt')
    .startAfter(lastDate)
    .limit(5);
```

But it seems that this would require a composite index (`categories.<categoryId>` and `createdAt`) for every single category. Is there any way around this?

In my case, it isn't feasible to create composite indices for every category since categories are user-generated, and could easily exceed 200 (the limit for composite indices in Firestore).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is doable by setting the value of each category to what you want to sort on. Firestore has a [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays) that covers this.

```
Post {
    title: ..
    ...
    categories: {
        cats: createdAt
        puppies: createdAt
    }   
}

let query = db.collection(`/posts`)
    .where(`categories.${categoryId}`, '>', 0)
    .orderBy(`categories.${categoryId}`)
    .startAfter(lastDate)
    .limit(5);
```

Comment: It looks little odd, but it is the only workaround currently.

Comment: Not to mention that this only work for two param, so if you were to add another parameter to the query this would not work. I wish Firebase adds the capability. But this was a great solution for the question thanks

Comment: You don't need the `where` for this to work, you can leave it out entirely.

Answer (score 21):

As far as I know Firestore should auto-generate those indexes. From the [documentation page on arrays, lists, and sets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays):

> Consider this alternative data structure, where each category is the key in a map and all values are true:
>
> ```
> // Sample document in the 'posts' collection
> {
>     title: "My great post",
>     categories: {
>         "technology": true,
>         "opinion": true,
>         "cats": true
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Now it's easy to query for all blog posts within a single category:
>
> ```
> // Find all documents in the 'posts' collection that are
> // in the 'cats' category.
> db.collection('posts')
>     .where('categories.cats', '==', true)
>     .get()
>     .then(() => {
>         // ...
>     });
> )
> ```
>
> This technique relies on the fact that **Cloud Firestore creates built-in indexes for all document fields, even fields in a nested map**.

While the lefthand-side of your where condition may be variable, that doesn't change the fact that these indexes should auto-generated (as far as I can see).

Comment: Hey @Frank, thanks for the answer. You are correct in simple cases, however the issue arrises when using the `orderBy` clause, which is required in order to be able to use `startAfter` for paginating the query. It seems that as soon as you add `orderBy`, you need to create a composite index, but I'm hoping there is another way

Comment: Aha... got it. That makes sense. And unfortunately I don't think there's any automatic index creation for that. The number of combinations would explode and go over the maximum number of indexes quickly. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen how do we write the query for db.collection('posts').where('roles.${uid}', '==', 'EDITOR' || 'VIEWER')?

Comment: @choopage-JekBao as explained in the documentation (bottom page of the link provided in the answer of this question) Logical OR queries. In this case, you should create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app

Answer (score 6):

Now Firestore allows the `array-contains` operator.
If you want to filter documents which contain specific value, try this.

**First, change Map field to Array field.**

```
Post {
    title: ..
    ...
    categories: [
        cats,
        puppies
    ]
}
```

**Second, use `array-contains` and `orderBy` for each different fields.**

```
let query = db.collection(`/posts`)
    .where('categories', 'array-contains', 'cats')
    .orderBy('createdAt')
    .startAfter(lastDate)
    .limit(5);
```

You can check the official document about `array-contains` operator from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership).

Comment: Unfortunately you currently can't chain `array-contains`

Answer (score 2):

Try restructuring your data store. [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) is very helpful here.

> #### Query limitations
>
> Cloud Firestore does not support the following types of queries:
>
> - Queries with range filters on different fields, as described in the previous section.
> - Single queries across multiple collections or subcollections. Each query runs against a single collection of documents. For more
>     information about how your data structure affects your queries, see
>     [Choose a Data
>     Structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data).
> - Queries of individual array members. You can, however, model and query array-like data using the techniques in [Working with Arrays,
>     Lists, and
>     Sets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays).
> - Logical OR queries. In this case, you should create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app.
> - Queries with a != clause. In this case, you should split the query into a greater-than query and a less-than query. For example, although
>     the query clause where("age", "!=", "30") is not supported, you can
>     get the same result set by combining two queries, one with the clause
>     where("age", "<", "30") and one with the clause where("age", ">", 30).

Answer (score 1):

Sorting on multiple where clauses is possible without creating on-the-fly indexes if you create a compound index on the doc id, then sort by it.

```
posts/field__2ls2kdlsk2
posts/field__3ksl2fjes2
posts/field__j23kslewsl
```

and your posts doc would look like `${field}__${createId()}`:

```js
let query = db.collection(`/posts`)
    .where(`categories.${categoryId}`, '==', true)
    .where(`categories.${categoryID2}`, '==', true)
    .orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
    .startAfter(docID)
    .limit(5);
```

J