# Firestore error - query requires an index but indexes might not be feasible?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database of items and need to find the ones with matching tags and fetch them 10 at a time (or any given number).

I've tried the following:

```
(await admin
                .firestore()
                .collection('media')
                .orderBy('id')
                .where('descriptions.tagSet.' + 'Test', '==', true)
                .where('descriptions.tagSet.' + 'Test2', '==', true)
                .startAt(start)
                .limit(10)
                .get()).docs;
```

At first I got an error about no index existing for 'id' so I created one using the link Firestore gave me.

However the next error I got was that there's no composite index for descriptions.tagSet.Test.

Unfortunately tags can be any arbitrary number of things, it doesn't seem feasible to have indexes for each possible tag (unless there's a quick programmatic way to create one?).

I'm not sure how to solve this issue, it seems like something which should be simple enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Firestore, how can you do a compound query involving a key in a map without creating an index for every key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980243/in-firestore-how-can-you-do-a-compound-query-involving-a-key-in-a-map-without-c)

Comment: @abraham Unfortunately no, I tried that idea on my own but it falls apart when you want to use multiple where queries. I've updated my question to make this apparent.

Comment: You won't be able to do that in a single query. A query on multiple keys requires an  index which has to be pre-defined. You could run two queries and combine them afterwards.

Comment: @abraham how can I do that in a performant way?

Comment: That's going to be very dependent on your particular data.