# How to create a composite index that includes a map?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection that contains three properties that I want to create a composite index for but keep getting an error that says I need a composite index for this query. This is the collection data model:

```
active: boolean
date: string
nameComponents: map
    "nameComponent": boolean
```

The document would look something like this:

```
active: true
date: "2019-02-18"
nameComponents:
    "pineapple": true
    "pie": true
```

The query would look something like this:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("someCollection").whereField("active", isEqualTo: true).whereField("nameComponents.pineapple", isEqualTo: true).whereField("date", isLessThanOrEqualTo: "2019-12-31").whereField("date", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: "2019-01-01")
```

I created the following composite index, without any luck:

**active: ascending, date: ascending, nameComponents: ascending**

How do I create a composite index for this query? And the links to create the composite index in the debugger always, since always, taken me to a webpage that says unknown error.

Comment: If the mechanism to create composite queries in the console isn't working, and you get some unknown error, you should reach out to Firebase support for that, and provide your full reproduction steps.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: To my question, can the query in this question even be performed? Can a composite index contain a map?

Comment: I've never tried, but the docs don't say that you can't.  You should still reach out to support if the console gives you an unknown error for any reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: this is, unfortunately, not possible. The composite index requires that each key in the map be given its own index. And with the limit that Firestore puts on how many composite indices are allowed in a database (not collection), this definitely is an antipattern for large maps.

Comment: But you can hack it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68961435/271450