# Flutter Firebase Query with Double where with orderBy asking composite key

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using dashchat plugin in flutter
https://pub.dev/packages/dash_chat with firestore database of firebase.

I am trying to implement whatsaApp like block chat pattern with chat item like below screenshot data structure.

And trying below query but it's adding composite index with static map value in conversationUserIdsBlock key but when I remove orderby it's working fine.

I have tried https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/index-map-field#disabling_indexes_for_subfields index exemptions through the console.

But it's not working.

```
 Future<Query> listQuery(MessageConversation messageConversation,
  {int limit,
  bool descending,
  MessageConversationItem startAfterMessageItem}) async {
final reference = this.reference();

if (limit == null) {
  limit = maxRecords();
}

if (descending == null) {
  descending = true;
}

debugPrint("Trying to load message conversation items: $limit");

Query query = reference
    .where('messageConversationId', isEqualTo: messageConversation.key)
    .where("conversationUserIdsBlock.DM0C6VxiJQbghjxCAl6v",
    isEqualTo: false) /// Static user id to check in map for block flag as of now
    .where("conversationUserIdsBlock.xJiZMVYapPNV7aehMH4O",
    isEqualTo: false) /// Static user id to check in map for block flag as of now
    .orderBy('createdAt', descending: descending)
    .limit(limit);

if (startAfterMessageItem != null) {
  debugPrint("Query with startAfterMessageItem");
  final snapshot =
      await this.reference().doc(startAfterMessageItem.key).get();
  query = query.startAfterDocument(snapshot);
}

return query;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: Aside from that, I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking from us. Did you create the composite index and is it not working?

Comment: complex index is taking value so it's not generalised solution for all dynamic id for check in map.@FrankvanPuffelen
I want to use dynamic id check in 'conversationUserIdsBlock' field which is map.

Above method is just for creating query and my other logic is working fine.
for example - working query as mentioned below, i am adding something on top of this query for additional feature of chat
   
Query query = reference
        .where('messageConversationId', isEqualTo: messageConversation.key)
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: descending)
        .limit(limit);

Comment: sorry - composite index not complex index

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68961435/271450